# VS2013 compile without linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, unmanaged

Is it possible to create a configuration in VS2013 for just compiling the files but skip linking for native C++ projects? I tried the `/c` option for `cl`, but I still see that the linker is invoked and the executable is getting generated?

Regards,

Comment: What about just doing it with a makefile or something that invokes the compiler directly? That provides much more fine grain control.

Comment: That's effectively what you do when you create static or dynamic library project...would either of those meet your needs?

Comment: You skip linking by creating a static library project.

Comment: What would be a purpose of compiling without linking?

Comment: My project needs to support v120_xp configuration for XP support. However that does not go well with existing SAL.h. So, my idea is to use the v120 platform toolset and do the analysis but not generate the binaries. So, it's some kind of hack to get around the code analysis issue with XP support

Comment: Clearly you asked the wrong question.  I'm not aware of SAL problems using v120_xp.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a clean method to do this from the IDE - here's a hint from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8we9bhf4.aspx):

> **To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio development environment**
>
> This option is not available from within the development environment.

Maybe you can think of a way how to break linker, maybe with two same named global variables in two source files, guarded by a preprocessor define defined in the compile only configuration?

Other way is to compile one file at the time, with `CTRL-F7` (or `Build -> Compile`).